# How to harden user/login password?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra, password

In High Sierra or Mojave, is it possible to harden our login password so that the hash is more difficult to crack? I'm not a crypto person, but can we increase the iterations or hashing algo strenth or something... to make the CPU work harder when using sudo and such? I know [Debian/Ubuntu distros are capable of such hardening](https://www.slashroot.in/how-are-passwords-stored-linux-understanding-hashing-shadow-utils). Is it possible in macOS?

Comment: can't you make your password stronger?  16-24 characters for example?  Or is this not the effect your looking for?

Comment: how about this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207054 Fingerprint

Comment: thanks for the responses, guys. this isn't quite the solution i'm looking for. i know its possible to make the hash harder to compute and crack. i'm pretty sure "iterations" or "transforms" is the term, like with keepassx https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83900/. it basically makes the login password hash much more resistant to bruteforce attacks